# Error in SSRS - while substract field value between 2 dataset into 3rd dataset - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, lookup

I'm trying to get the dataset3 column value by calculating (substracting) dataset1 column value and dataset2 column value and I'm displaying dataset3 column value .

Dataset1:

```
    FieldName1 - ID
    FieldName2 - Name
```

Dataset2:

```
    FieldName1 - ID
    FieldName2 - Name
```

Dataset3:

```
 FieldName1 - Exp [=First(Fields!ID.Value, "Dataset1")-First(Fields!ID.Value, "Dataset2")] 
 FieldName2 - Exp [=First(Fields!Name.Value, "Dataset1")-First(Fields!Name.Value, "Dataset2")]
```

Error msg:

> The expression used for the calculated field '=First(Fields!ID.Value,
>   "Dataset1")-First(Fields!Name.Value, "Dataset2")' includes an
>   aggregate, RowNumber, RunningValue, Previous or lookup function.
>   Aggregate, RowNumber, RunningValue, Previous and lookup functions
>   cannot be used in calculated field expressions.

**Example:**

Dataset1:

```
ID  Name
1    A
2    B
3    C
```

Dataset2:

```
ID  Name
2    B
4    D
```

Output:

```
Dataset3:
ID Name
1   A
3   C
```

Please help!

Note: I tried with LOOKUP function but no luck.

```
=Lookup(First(Fields!ID.Value, "Dataset1"),First(Fields!ID.Value, "Dataset2"),First(Fields!Name.Value, "Dataset1"),Dataset1)
```

Comment: are you creating the dataset3 with calculated fields and those expression ?

Comment: @BhupeshC Yes. you are correct.

Comment: well you can't create a dataset which in turn references to another dataset

Comment: @BhupeshC Ok. Instead of create new dataset. Can I display the calculated value into report table.

Comment: yes that's possible using lookup()

Comment: I am puzzled by why you want to subtract `First(Fields!Name.Value, "Dataset2")` from `First(Fields!Name.Value, "Dataset1")`. Based on your example, `Fields!Name.Value` is a text value.

Comment: @bhupeshC Yes I tried but getting error. Can you help me to solve this?

Comment: @Ann L Needs to substract between values Since I tried with that condition.

Comment: @BhupeshC, As you said I used LOOKUP like this but no luck =Lookup(First(Fields!ID.Value, "Dataset1"),First(Fields!ID.Value, "Dataset2"),First(Fields!Name.Value, "Dataset1"),Dataset1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you create a report tablix, you have to assign it a dataset, you can check that by going into tablix properties, general and check the dataset name.

Now when you already have a dataset assigned to your tablix, you can get the values from other dataset by using `lookup()`

Keeping the scenario in mind here, you can create a report tablix and assign dataset1 to it and then create an expression in that tablix as follows :-

`lookup(Fields!ID.Value,Fields!ID.Value,Fields!Name.Value,"Dataset2")`

This will lookup in `Dataset2` using values of the ID column from `Dataset1` and when matched, it will return Name column from `Dataset2`

**[More about `Lookup()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx)**